# Amazon S3 security credentials per bucket

Tags: security, amazon-s3, credentials, bucket

I was wondering if it was possible to generate security credentials per individual Amazon S3 bucket. I am working with a developer and would like to grant him access only to the bucket we are working with. It's not a trust issue, it's more a concern that he'll delete the wrong bucket or its contents.

For example: If we were working on an application that used a bucket called `test-application` I could generate the credentials for just that one bucket. These credentials would not allow access to other buckets in my account.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: Some policy stuff I did around s3 https://github.com/davidwebstar34/policyninja/blob/master/s3_homedir.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask him to create an Amazon account if he doesn't have one.  Then you can just grant him an access to one of your buckets.   To make things easier you can use one of the GUI tools such as S3Fox http://www.s3fox.net/